# Tomcat server.xml parser

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, tomcat, xml-parsing

I need to modify from code, Tomcat's `server.xml`.
Ok it is just an XML file and there are plenty of ways to parse it but I was wondering if there is already an API specifically for `server.xml` (e.g. from Apache) and will not have to write any code to parse it.
So is there?
Note:The program to parse the `server.xml` will do it "offline" i.e. it is not part of a `Valve` or some other component that has access to the container

Answer (score 2):

Generate xsd by xml (using IDEA or [something](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/))  -> generate jaxb representation by xsd (using jaxb) will not take long time

Comment: i would like to do this, but jaxb get mad (of course is my fault but i'm not able to understand how) and return me list of serializable instead of my appropriate bean and this block me

Answer (score 1):

You coudl use the same parsing routines Tomcat uses for loading `server.xml`, i.e. [Commons Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/). This way you can reuse a regular Tomcat `catalina.jar` and avoid generated code than can get outdated.

From the [startup sequence](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/architecture/startup/serverStartup.txt) documentation:

```
        b3) createStartDigester() 
            Configures a digester for the main server.xml elements like
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer (can change of course :)
            org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources
                Stores naming resources in the J2EE JNDI tree
            org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener
                implements events for start/stop of major components
            org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService
                The single entry for a set of connectors,
                so that a container can listen to multiple connectors
                ie, single entry
            org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteConnector
                Connectors to listen for incoming requests only
            It also adds the following rulesets to the digester
                NamingRuleSet
                EngineRuleSet
                HostRuleSet
                ContextRuleSet
        b4) Load the server.xml and parse it using the digester
            Parsing the server.xml using the digester is an automatic
            XML-object mapping tool, that will create the objects defined in server.xml
            Startup of the actual container has not started yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it even a good practice to do it , programmatically ?

Comment: super useful if you're making an installer